# Is it possible to install Windows 10 on a ubuntu VPS using SSH?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, vps, operating-system

I have to start an executable on a vps, but the "customer" rented an ubuntu one. I tried to install Wine as many sites and questions on stackoverflow suggested, but this VPS lacks some windows files needed to start the executable. The VPS only allows to install ubuntu, centOS and linux from the control panel. The only access i have to the machine is through SSH or SFTP consoles. Is there any other way to force windows on the VPS or do we have to rent a new one?

Comment: Tell your customer that you need Windows. Everything else will be neither usable nor manageable.

Answer (score 2):

With ssh you can create a tunnel for X, then you could install X on the linux, followed by VirtualBox into which you can install Windows.

Everything graphical would then happen on your local system.